# Pokemon keep running at first throw and the pokestops won't Roll and just stay blue

Tags: pokemon-go

This might be late but my Pokemon all run away after the first throw. What is causing this?

Comment: sounds like you are [softbanned](http://heavy.com/games/2016/08/how-know-if-banned-from-pokemon-go-was-i-soft-ban-temporary-permanent-email-pokemongo-appeal-what-do-fix/)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have been softbanned by Niantic. This usually happens when the game detected suspicious movements, such as jumping from one location to another or moving too fast.

Softbans are temporary and usually last for a short period of time, from minutes to hours. The symptoms of a softban are similar to what you have encountered -- all Pokémon run away at first ball throw, Pokéstops do not respond and you cannot challenge gyms.

You should simply stop playing for a while until the softban is over. Playing right now doesn't do anything other than waste your resources. To avoid getting softbanned, avoid playing while on highways or simply when inside moving vehicles.